# Why weak supervision works?

Tags: dataset, semi-supervised-learning, labeling

I've learned that weak supervision combines multiple labeling methods to generate labels for a large dataset. I can't understand why generated labels can be used to train a more accurate model than all those labeling methods. Can't we use weak supervision as a combined classifier model instead of just labeling the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak supervision only works better than classic labeling in the case of weak data, but with a large volume.

Why? Because it considers several incomplete features and applies them to a general probabilistic model including noise and empty rows (different scenarios are built automatically), which is not possible with classic labeling that usually considers one or two complete features (= more deterministic).

Comment: Can't we use weak supervision as a classifier? And how a classifier trained on a weak supervision labeled dataset can be more accurate than weak supervision?

Comment: Is your data weak? (i.e having a lot of missing values) If not, there is no valid reason to apply weak supervision.

Comment: Let's say it is a dataset for detecting bots on Twitter. 10 percent have been labeled manually and it is using those labeled records with weak supervision to label the remaining records. Data is standard from API. I can't understand why a model trained on the whole dataset can be better than a model trained on 10 percent.

Comment: The 10 percent are complete, not weak, right? Consequently, if you train your model on complete data only, this is not weak supervision and there is no need for it (or I've missed something).